# Set mermaid configuration in Quarto to change default width to 100%

Tags: r, quarto, mermaid

Per the mermaid documentation (bottom of page in the below link), I should be able to change the diagram width width with the following arguments

https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html

```
mermaid.flowchartConfig = {
    width: 100%
}
```

However, does anyone know how to set this in Quarto and R? When I try to have it as standalone code chunks it doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example of a quarto file with mermaid graph example.